# Exchange web service set organizer of the appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices

When I use Service account to add a new appointment, the organizer always the user of Credentials to Exchange service, I want to set the organizer to another user, but the organizer property is readonly, how can I achieve that?

```html
           var appointment = new Appointment(_service.ExchangeService);
            
            if (exchangeAppointment.Participants.Any() && exchangeAppointment.Participants != null)
            {
                foreach (var participant in exchangeAppointment.Participants)
                {
                    appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(participant);
                }
            }
            appointment.Resources.Add(exchangeAppointment.RoomAdIdentityEmail);
            appointment.Location = string.Join(",", appointment.Resources);
            appointment.Subject = exchangeAppointment.Subject;
            appointment.Body = exchangeAppointment.Body;
            appointment.Start = exchangeAppointment.StartTime;
            appointment.End = exchangeAppointment.EndTime;
            appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Organizer is going to be set based on the Calendar your saving the Appointment to, when you using a Service Account your creating the Appointment OnBehalf of the Organizer so you would need set the Save location to the calendar of the Organizer you want eg

```
Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "user@ddomain.com"), SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

The other option is to use EWS Impersonation and then Impersonate the Organizer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I use this, it throw an exception "The specified folder could not be found in the store.", I set the email to correct email of Exchange server

Comment: That error means you don't have rights to the Mailbox in question so you need grant the account your using Access to the Mailbox your trying to create the appointment in via Add-Mailboxpermissions (or Outlook Delegates)